# Python 2 IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve Project Euler Problem 15.

I've put some arrays in mainarray.

I get an IndexError: list index out of range on line 33 and don't know why. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Here is my Code:

```
def make_file(num_matrix):
    file = open("euler15.csv", "w")

    for a in num_matrix:
        for b in a:
            file.write(str(b) + ",")
        file.write("\n")
    file.close()

mainarray = []

act_cell_row = 1
act_cell_column = 1
summand_1 = 0
summand_2 = 1
x = 1
y = 0
for c in range(0,20):
    mainarray.append([])
for d in range(2,22):
    mainarray[0].append(d)
for e in range(3,22):
    mainarray[x].append(e)
    x += 1

for f in mainarray:
    for g in f:
        print "act_cell_column ", act_cell_column
        print "act_cell_row ", act_cell_row
        print "summand_2 ", summand_2
        print "summand_1 ", summand_1   
        akt_feld = (mainarray[summand_1][summand_2]) + (mainarray[summand_2][summand_1])
        mainarray[act_cell_row][act_cell_column] = akt_feld
        if y < 18:
            summand_2 += 1
            act_cell_column += 1
            y += 1
    summand_1 += 1
    summand_2 = 1
    act_cell_row += 1
    act_cell_column = 1

make_file(mainarray)
result = mainarray[19][19]
print "RESULT: ", result
```

Comment: You need to include the full traceback. Line 31 in your code is `print "summand_1 ", summand_1 ` on here.

Comment: MAINARRAY:  [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21]]
x gets to 19. because in main arrays are 20 arrays. from 0 to 19

Comment: Also you forget to reset `summand_1`, after `for g in f` loop.

Comment: It was line 33 sorry. summand_1 shouldn't be reseted after the loop because it's the row. It gets to 19. but summand_2 should go in row 1 from 1 to 20 and in row 2 from 1 to 20 and so on

Comment: Here the full traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                   
  File "15_t.py", line 33, in <module>                                                                                               
    mainarray[act_cell_row][act_cell_column] = akt_feld                                                                              
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: Just an aside - you can solve this problem in about 4 lines if you use itertools permutations. But alas I have tried and get a memory error

Answer (score 0):

To check, when error occures, you can add this code before `akt_feld` assignment:

```
try:
    _ = mainarray[summand_1][summand_2]
except IndexError:
    print("something wrong with this indexes", summand_1, summand_2)
```

Or just call `mainarray[1][1]`.

```
In [7]: print(mainarray[1])
[3]

In [8]: print(mainarray[1][1])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-e23bb5ccbc5a> in <module>()
----> 1 print(mainarray[1][1])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: With the try and except, the error is like before. I doesn't print "something wrong with this indexes"